# How to intercept a submit button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and a submit button.

I want to do a quick check on some of the fields (if one isn't filled in, then to blank some of the others).

I would rather not change the HTML for the button, I would like to just to do this in jQuery and not add any "onclick" attributes to the button.

HTML:

```
<input class="cssButton button_in_cart" type="submit" value="Add to Bag" style="width: 80px;">
```

jQuery (attempted):

```
$("input.button_in_cart").mousedown(function () {
    alert("clicked");   
});
```

This doesn't work, it still submits the form without showing the alert. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a form? If yes, then please post the whole form instead of the submit button only. on "submit" is what you would ideally use.

Comment: `$(body).on( "submit" , "form" , function(){ alert("ok"); return true;})`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not use any form of click event for form processing as keyboard submission will bypass your code!

Use the `submit` event handler instead and return false (or `e.preventDefault()`) to stop the submit proceeding.

e.g.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
   // Do your validation here
   // ...
   // Then conditionally stop the submit from firing
   if (someValidateFails){
      e.preventDefault()
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like the form to submit, but only after doing the check of a field. I will look into this.

Comment: @user2924019: Just check your field and call e.preventDefault() if it is not correct. This is how most client-side validation systems work.

Comment: Many thanks again, I am using this method. Will mark as answered as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Philip Clegg: That is pointless for this case, as they are in the middle of a submit anyway. Just validate and allow it through, or `preventDefault()`

Comment: @PhilipClegg and btw this would create kind of infinite loop, triggering same event again and again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return value of the function to prevent the form submission

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
```

and function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

In case of Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m if above code does not work, please set the event handler's parameter's returnValue field to false to get it to work.

Comment: It is always best to *not* mix jQuery within inline event handlers. Just do it the jQuery way. That will avoid Chrome problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

make type as 'button' first

```
<input class="cssButton button_in_cart" type="submit" value="Add to Bag" style="width: 80px;">


$("input.button_in_cart").mousedown(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked");   
    // do the form submit
   document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: As per the question, I would rather not modify the HTML of the button. This is generated elsewhere on a large system and I don't want to mess anything else up.

Comment: @user2924019 In that case, I have the made changes.

Comment: This would only work if you stop the button being a `submit`, otherwise *keyboard-based* form submission (e.g. `enter`) will bypass your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to "stop" an event.
The first one is to `return false;` and the other one is to `e.preventDefault();`.
Teh difference in these two ways is that using `e.preventDefault();` will stop the entire event from proceeding and won't propagate the DOM.

I would use the following:

```
$("input.button_in_cart").mousedown(function () {
    alert("clicked");   
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Don't ever use click events with forms... Keyboard submission will bypass it.

Comment: You are wrong `e.preventDefault();` doesn't stop event to bubble  EDIT: i guess you just made a typo in answer i want instead to 'paste' `return false;` :)